# set hidden field value in document.ready and get its value in pageload event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to set hidden fied value in document.ready function and get it in PageLoad event but its value always empty where I am wrong please suggest me.
My javascript code is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=hdnMiddlediv.ClientID %>').value = '')
        { document.getElementById('<%=hdnMiddlediv.ClientID %>').value = 'test'; }
    });
</script>
```

c#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string val = hdnMiddlediv.Value;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string val2 = hdnMiddlediv.Value;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**Comparision(==/===)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) operator instead of [**Assignment(=)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) operator. If you use assignment operator, the condition will always evaluate to **false** and your code inside `if` will never execute.

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=hdnMiddlediv.ClientID %>').value == '')
//                                                               ^^
```

If you're using `jQuery` use `val()` to get/set value of an element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#<%=hdnMiddlediv.ClientID %>').val()) {
        $('#<%=hdnMiddlediv.ClientID %>').val('test');
    }
});
```